# How to hide the soft keyboard in .Net Maui when using an external keyboard?

Tags: maui

I have a .Net Maui 7 app.

I'm trying to use an external barcode scanner that works like a an external keyboard.

To use it, I'm creating a standard entry in which the code detected by the scanner will be set.

```
        // Button to start scanning
        private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.MyEntry.Focus();   // Focus on the entry        
            HideSoftKeyboard();
        }
        
        // Hide the soft keyboard
        void HideSoftKeyboard()
        {
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
            {
    #if ANDROID
                handler.PlatformView.EditorAction += (s, e) =>
                {
                    handler.PlatformView.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null;
                };

    #elif IOS

                handler.PlatformView.EditingDidBegin += (s, e) =>
                {
                    handler.PlatformView.InputView=new UIKit.UIView();
                    
                };
    #endif
            });
        }
```

The previous code hides the soft keyboard but when using the external scanner, as long as the first character is typed in the Entry, the keyboard shows again. And typing is very slow.

How can I disable the soft keyboard? Or any idea how to use an external scanner as a keyboard?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SirRufo In this case which view should I use to listen for the key up/down please ?

Comment: I tried for example a simple maui page, but I couldn't find any Key up/down events on the page to create a handler.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I deleted my comment, as it is not usable on MAUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and found that the code `handler.PlatformView.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null;` and `handler.PlatformView.InputView=new UIKit.UIView();` didn't execute.

So you can add this code into the Page's `OnHandlerChanged` method. Such as:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
    base.OnHandlerChanged();

#if ANDROID
    (MyEntry.Handler.PlatformView as AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatEditText).InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null;
#elif IOS
    (MyEntry.handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.Maui.Platform.MauiTextField).InputView=new UIKit.UIView();
#endif
}
```

I tested this on the android. And the softkeyboard will be always disabled for this entry.